# Local Data Address Does not belong to any of this hosts local interfaces

Tags: java, exception, network-programming, jmf

```
byte[] ip = new byte[4];
        ip[0] = (byte) 192;
        ip[1] = (byte) 168;
        ip[2] = (byte) 1;
        ip[3] = (byte) 8;

SessionAddress localSessionAddr = new SessionAddress(
                InetAddress.getByAddress(ip), LOCAL_RTP_PORT);
```

Throws: Local Data Address Does not belong to any of this hosts local interfaces

**[solution and reason]**

The problem is JMF seems to use InetAddress.getAllByName() which gives (in most cases) only single IP address as it may not be in the /etc/hosts. It can be sorted out by setting your interface ip (say eth0, wlan0) in /etc/hosts [[1]](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1279945).

```
>  cat /etc/hosts
> 127.0.0.1 localhost
> 127.0.1.1 noor
> 192.168.1.8 noor
```

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order of the bytes? (Network order versus host order)

Comment: You mean in the /etc/hosts? Btw, the output show here is after the editing of /etc/hosts , not the one before the issue.